# Using \tikzset to replace options for tikzpicture without a named style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, options, tikzset

I am trying to concentrate often used options for a `tikzpicture` under a `tikzset` command in the preamble, to share among different pictures. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% \tikzset{every picture/.append style{line cap=round, line width=1.5pt, {-Latex[round]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [line cap=round, line width=1.5pt, {-Latex[round]}]
\draw [blue](0, 0) -- (0.5, 1);
\draw [red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file compiles well as is, but does not if I comment out the options after `\begin{tikzpicture}` and uncomment the line with `tikzset` in the preamble.

How can I get the `tikzset` command to work so that I may, dispense with the options after `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Trying what you have suggested gives me the correct arrow tip but the `line cap` and `line width` are not recognized and are default. I want an invocation that can set all three in one go. Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an `=` in your `\tikzset` command. But additionally, I wouldn't use `.append` for this but instead use `.style`:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line cap=round, line width=1.5pt, {-Latex[round]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [blue](0, 0) -- (0.5, 1);
\draw [red] (0, 0) -- (1, 0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a foolish error on my part! Thank you @Alan Munn. It now works as I intended.

Comment: You might want to explain why you prefer `.style`, since this really isn't obvious from the manual. @chandra If you're curious, `\tikzset{/handlers/.add code/.show code,/handlers/.code/.show code}` will show you (what I assume to be) the reason on the terminal ;).

Comment: I have just started reading `87.1.2  Quick Guide to Using the Key Mechanism` in the manual. I had always wondered about the dot. Now it is clearer. Thanks @cfr.